# Rewriting a redirected URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my setup :

I have a website located at www.cabsh.org/drupal

I want to use mod_rewrite to do 2 things :

1. Redirect www.cabsh.org to http://www.cabsh.org/drupal/index.php (I got this one)
2. Rewrite /www.cabsh.org/drupal/index.php to www.cabsh.org/site/index.php

I cannot figure how to achieve the 2nd point.  I'm using .htaccess files since I cannot use the main server configuration.  Can anyone help me getting this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Your site is under /drupal. Why do you want to redirect /drupal/index.php to /site/index.php?

Comment: Well... Maybe I wasn't specific but I could also rewrite (not redirect " != [R] " ) /drupal to /site

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you want. If your Drupal site is at /drupal, why do you want to rewrite requests to that folder to /site? Or did you want to get to /drupal by going to /site? (And if so, why not just change the name of the Drupal directory?)

Comment: Ya actually, all I want is to hide drupal to rename it with site.  I know I could just rename the folder but I wanted to do it with mod_rewrite so I can practice.  I still don't know how to achieve it using mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

From what I get from your comment, you just want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Prevent a request directly to the /drupal folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/drupal/
RewriteRule ^drupal/(.*)$ /site/$1 [R=301,L]

# Change a request for /site/(anything) to /drupal/(anything)
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /drupal/$1
```

Be careful though, since Drupal (being in the Drupal folder) might generate links that point to /drupal instead of /site, which is seemingly not what you want.